# React Native - Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

i am learning react native and i was importing a AppLoading to use custom fonts i a got this error:

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

my app.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo-app-loading';

const getFonts = () =>
  Font.loadAsync({
    'nunito-regular': require('./assets/Fonts/Nunito-Regular.ttf'),
    'nunito-bold': require('./assets/Fonts/Nunito-Bold.ttf'),
  });

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);

  if (fontsLoaded) {
    return <Home />;
  } else {
    return <AppLoading startAsync={getFonts} onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded} />;
  }
}
```

my Home.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 24,
  },

  titleText: {
    fontFamily: 'nunito-bold',
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

This is the problem.

You import this:

```
import { AppLoading } from "expo-app-loading";
```

[The docs say](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading/) to import this:

```
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
```

Comment: It worked but now is maing an error but i cant see the log i just know that have an error because of the onError propertie of OnLoading

Comment: I changed some things after that comment and it is working